# Webpack chunks are not splitting properly

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

After numerous tries, I come to the conclusion there is something wrong with the test regex but unable to fix it.

This seems `\.?[\\/]node_modules[\\/]((?!react-pdf)).*` with [regex-tester](https://www.regextester.com/) but not working

```
splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
      minSize: 0,
      cacheGroups: {
        patientVendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](!react-pdf)[\\/]/,
          name: 'patientVendor',
          chunks: 'all',
        },
        reactPDFVendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](react-pdf)[\\/]/,
          name: 'reactPDFChunk',
          chunks: 'all',
        },
      },
    },
  }
```

Expected:
different chunk for react-pdf
different chunk for every other module with the name patientVendor.[hash].js

Current:
different chunk for react-pdf
different chunk for every other module with the name [hash].js

Answer (score 0):

The following regex solved the issue, also I didn't explicitly wanted a named bundle for pdf-js

```
splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          // just need to exclude these they will created by webpack as other chunk
          test: /.?[\\/]node_modules[\\/](?!(react-pdf|pdfjs-dist)).*?/,
          name: 'patientVendors',
          chunks: 'all',
        },
      },
    },
```